# Need a circular FFT convolution in Python

Tags: python, scipy, convolution

I need a faster analog of

```
scipy.signal.convolve2d(data, filter, boundary="wrap", mode="same")
```

Cannot you advice me how to replace it?

P.S. `scipy.signal.fftconvolve` is fast enough, but it does not have `boundary` option and I cannot make it work in circular convolution mode.

Comment: I think the reason there's no boundary option is because FFT doesn't work like that. And exactly what do you mean by a "circular" convolution? Edit: never mind, I found a definition on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_convolution).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you compute the following:

```
from scipy.fftpack import fft2, ifft2

f2 = ifft2(fft2(data, shape=data.shape) * fft2(filter, shape=data.shape)).real
```

then `f2` contains the same values as `convolve2d(data, filt, boundary='wrap', mode='same')`, but the values are shifted ("rolled", in numpy terminology) in each axis. (This is an application of the [convolution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem).)

Here's a short function that rolls the result to the give same result as the `convolve2d` function call:

```
def fftconvolve2d(x, y):
    # This assumes y is "smaller" than x.
    f2 = ifft2(fft2(x, shape=x.shape) * fft2(y, shape=x.shape)).real
    f2 = np.roll(f2, (-((y.shape[0] - 1)//2), -((y.shape[1] - 1)//2)), axis=(0, 1))
    return f2
```

For example,

```
In [91]: data = np.random.rand(256, 256)

In [92]: filt = np.random.rand(16, 16)

In [93]: c2d = convolve2d(data, filt, boundary='wrap', mode='same')

In [94]: f2 = fftconvolve2d(data, filt)
```

Verify that the results are the same:

```
In [95]: np.allclose(c2d, f2)
Out[95]: True
```

Check the performance:

```
In [96]: %timeit c2d = convolve2d(data, filt, boundary='wrap', mode='same')
44.9 ms ± 77.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [97]: %timeit f2 = fftconvolve2d(data, filt)
5.23 ms ± 11.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

The FFT version is *much* faster (but note that I chose the dimensions of `data` to be a power of 2).

Comment: Which one of these has initially the correct ordered output? The FFT version or the scipy conv warp version?